# When avoiding MSSQL Deadlock on FK insert - is it good ideat to just remove FK?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, deadlock

we have following situation.

There is parent child between two tables with FK constraint.

When there is higher concurrent access when inserting data with FK id, we are receiving deadlock exception from SQLServer.

On of the proposed solutions could be - just remove that FK, add index and try to keep data integrity using transaction and proper BE code.

Are there any other reasons not to do it, except those obvious that without FK nothing guarantees that data would be consistent (eg. in case of bug in BE code)?

Note: I am against this solution, because it is just hiding problem with taking tech debt loan.

Thx

Ivos

Comment: It would help if you showed more details: the tables' structure (CREATE TABLE statement plus indexes), the queries or procedures that are used for the insert and the deadlock (graph xml).

Comment: Are you using MERGE by any chance?

Comment: You say "remove that FK, add index" ... Do you currently have an index to support that FK constraint? How do you see the need for that index ONLY when you drop the FK?

Comment: And to add to AMtwo's point, how do you know for sure that it is directly the FK that's the problem? Sometimes adding indexes can make deadlock problems worse, sometimes they help, sometimes they make no difference, all dependent on what the actual source of the deadlock is. As ypercube mentioned, seeing the queries and the deadlock graph would be helpful here, for determining the source of the issue.

Comment: You should add the index *without* removing the FK, as that will prevent the deadlock from happening. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/71501241/14868997

Comment: Thx for your respnses. I will try to find info you requeted (it is not part of application I am participating, so I do not have that detail now, I am just very cautious when somebody wants to solve deadlock like that).
About "the deadlock (graph xml)" what exactly you mean by that?